Definition of relative error in floating point conversion
Sorry, this question might be quite naive. When we talk about conversion to floating point numbers, the relative error for x is defined as $\frac{|x-fl(x)|}{|x|}$. Using base $10$ for simplicity, if $x=d_1d_2\dots d_N$ is converted to a $k$-digit decimal floating point through either chopping or rounding, then $\frac{|x-fl(x)|}{|x|}$ is bounded by analyzing $$\frac{(.d_1d_2\dots d_k \dots d_N - .f_1f_2\dots f_k)\cdot 10^c}{x},$$ where
$c=\lfloor \log(x)+1\rfloor$ (namely, the power of $10$ that $x$ is divided by to have it start with a decimal point), and $f_1 \dots f_k$ the mantra. Rewriting $x$,
$$\frac{(.d_1d_2\dots d_k \dots d_N - .f_1f_2\dots f_k)\cdot 10^c}{(.d_1d_2\dots d_N) \cdot 10^c} = 
\frac{(.d_1d_2\dots d_k \dots d_N - .f_1f_2\dots f_k)}{(.d_1d_2\dots d_N)}
,$$
and the numerator is bounded below by $(\frac{1}{10})^k$ or $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{10})^k$, and the denominator is bounded above by $.1$ since $d_1>0$, so we get
$$\frac{|x-fl(x)|}{|x|} \leq \frac{1}{.1}(\frac{1}{10})^{k}=(\frac{1}{10})^{k-1},$$ or similarly
$$\frac{|x-fl(x)|}{|x|} \leq \frac{1}{.1}\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{10})^{k}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{10})^{k-1}.$$
However, I notice in this idea, for the denominator, we just use that $d_1\dots d_n \geq .1$.   My question is, is there an intuitive reason we use $.d_1\dots d_n$ in the denominator at all, meaning, why don't we define the relative error as $$\frac{x-fl(x)}{10^c}?$$ If the above steps are followed, the simplified denominator is now $1$ and the bound is directly $(\frac{1}{10})^{k}$ or $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{10})^{k}$. I'm curious because intuitively, it seems like for a relative error you'd care more about the error relative to $10^c$ rather than $x$ itself.   For example, if you convert $1.234$ to a 3-digit floating point by chopping, you get $.123 \cdot 10^1$, and the relative error is
$$\frac{.0004 \cdot 10^1}{.1234 \cdot 10^1}.$$ This error is independent of where the decimal is in $1234$. But if we convert $.2344$ to a 3-digit floating point number, the relative error is now $$\frac{.0004 \cdot 10^1}{.2344 \cdot 10^1}.$$ Why is it helpful to make the error depend on the "relative" digits ($.d_1 \dots d_N$) of $x$ in the sense that we also divide by it, in addition to the computation $x-x^*$ involving it? It currently seems more natural/useful to me to just care about $.d_1 \dots d_N$ in the numerator but not also in the denominator, but I'm not sure. Is there possible any insight for this? Thx
(Note: I think, also, that relative error is defined as the relative error to $x$, but I don't yet follow why this definition is more relevant than say the relative error to $10^c$ in the book I'm reading. Thx)
